# toggle doesn't work on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggle, media

I am trying to build a responsive Website.
I've never used the @media tag before, so I am not sure if I did anything wrong.

The nav should be a slidetoggle menu when the window size is smaller than 550px.

It works when I decrease the browser window, but not on my iPhone.
I want the nav changing to the toggle at 550px and the header height changing to the toggle height (2em).

I hope you can help me.

HTML:

```
<meta name="viewport" content"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">


<div id="header">
    <section id="menubar">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="menubutton" href="#menu"><img src="images/menu.png" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
        <nav class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="test.html">test</a></li>
                <li><a href="test.html">test</a></li>
                <li><a href="test.html">test</a></li>
                <li><a href="test.html">test</a></li>
                <li><a href="test.html">test</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
ul {
margin:0px;
padding:0px; }

li {
list-style:square;
font-weight:100;
color:#000000;
line-height:1em;
padding:0em; }

a {text-decoration: none; }

div#header {
position: fixed;
height: 6.250em;
width: 100%;
background-color: #fff;
top: 0;
z-index: 999; }

#menubar {
display:block;
background:#ffffff; }

#menubar ul {
display:block;
width:2em;
padding:0.9em; }

#menubar ul li {
display:inline; }

#menubar ul li a.menubutton {
display:none; }

#menubar img {
width:90%;
height:auto;
max-width:100%; }

nav ul {
display:block;
position: absolute;
left: 15%;
bottom: 0.625em;
font-size: 0.875em; }

nav ul li {
display:inline;
margin:0em 0.625em 0em 0em; }

nav ul li a {
color:#000; }

nav ul li a:hover {
color:#cc9900; }

nav ul li a.active {
color:#cc9900; }

@media screen and (min-width:600px) {
nav.nav {
    display:block !important;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width:550px) {
#menubar ul li a.menubutton {
    display:block;
}   
nav {
    display:none;
    height:auto;
}
nav ul li {
    display:block;
    margin:0.2em 0em 0.2em 0em;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width:550px) {
div#header {
height: 2em !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width:550px) {
div#content {
top: 2em !important;
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: The nav should be a slidetoggle menu when the window size is smaller than 550px.

Comment: Please update your question with that info. You must also include what's going wrong, and what you expect to happen in your question.

Comment: ok changed it, thank you!

Comment: Np, just remember that whenever you ask a question here. People need to know exactly whats going wrong, and what you expect to happen to help you (usually).

Answer (score 0):

My Technique is, after every mediaquery I colorise one element in a heavy color, so i can see whats happening when.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  header { background-color: red; }
}
```

For me - 320px = red, 480px = orange, 760px = green

greet;s

Comment: Thanks satinez, I tried it. But it still only works in the browser. Even if I only use the little code with the color, there is a change, but on my iPhone - nothing.

Comment: - Which resolution does the Iphone have?
- Did u added the right Meta Tag in HTML?
- Is the Zoom at 100% ?

Maybe leave the maximum-scale in Meta.

Comment: Maybe u can give us some example site, or build it with jsfiddle.  
So we can see and help better.

Comment: Check out www.niklasheinecke.com/test

Comment: Ok, thanks. I see the error.  1. The Mediaquery is working fine.  2. U have to define what will happen when u click on the "HamburgerIcon", i dont see it defined.  This toggle is not defined somewhere, am I right?  3. U can do it with css only or mix with js.

Comment: well I put the jquery in the <head> part of the html document, it has worked before, but when I changed the header height in stopped working. I realize that I have to problems here, first the toggle doesnt work properly, sec. the mediaquery doesn't work or at least on my iphone 6s it doesn't work.

Comment: http://www.responsinator.com/?url=www.niklasheinecke.com%2Ftest

Cant help, need more information.

Comment: Maybe this can help open your Menu without javascript.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqKZVd

Comment: thank, I am going to try it out. Still not sure why the responsinator shows it  right but all my iPhones (4,5,6s) show the Website in the browser mode.

Comment: try to change the meta tag (viewport), maybe its wrong or too much ; something. And check the zoom mode, sometime the browser hangs up. Maybe try to clear the Browsercache.